# Why does my code result in a blackscreen?

Tags: c++, calculator

i"am learning c++ and decided to make a simple calculator and when i compiled the project and ran it all it showed is a black screen. Btw im running MS VSCode 2022. Thanks in advance for help! :)
`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int konec = 0;
    double cislox = 0;
    double cisloy = 0;
    int operace = 0;
    double vysledek1 = 0;
    double vysledek2 = 0;
    double vysledek3 = 0;
    double vysledek4 = 0;

    while (konec == 0); {
        cout << "Vítejte v kalkulačce Ver. 0.1" << endl;
        cout << "stiskněte 1 pro sčítání, 2 pro odčítání, 3 pro násobení, 4 pro dělení" << endl;
        cin >> operace;
        switch (operace) {
        case 1:
            cout << "Zadejte číslo X" << endl;
            cin >> cislox;
            cout << "Zadejte číslo Y" << endl;
            cin >> cisloy;
            vysledek1 = cislox + cisloy;
            cout << cislox << "+" << cisloy << "=" << vysledek1;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "Zadejte číslo X" << endl;
            cin >> cislox;
            cout << "Zadejte číslo Y" << endl;
            cin >> cisloy;
            vysledek2 = cislox - cisloy;
            cout << cislox << "-" << cisloy << "=" << vysledek2;
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "Zadejte číslo X" << endl;
            cin >> cislox;
            cout << "Zadejte číslo Y" << endl;
            cin >> cisloy;
            vysledek3 = cislox * cisloy;
            cout << cislox << "*" << cisloy << "=" << vysledek3;
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "Zadejte číslo X" << endl;
            cin >> cislox;
            cout << "Zadejte číslo Y" << endl;
            cin >> cisloy;
            vysledek2 = cislox / cisloy;
            cout << cislox << "/" << cisloy << "=" << vysledek4;
            break;
        }
        cout << "chcete ukoncit program?" << "1 = ANO; 0 = NE" << endl;
        cin >> konec;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`

Well, i tried cheking all the code, but there should be no mistakes. Maybe im compiling it wrong? (im a MS VSCode user only for a while)

Comment: `while (konec == 0); { ... }` is equal to `while (konec == 0) { /* Empty loop body */ } { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in the while loop:

```cpp
while (konec == 0); {
```

The `;` on there makes it an infinite while loop that does not execute any code, since it's empty. The correct way should be:

```cpp
while (konec == 0) {
```

Answer (score 2):

you put a `;` after the `while(konec)`. Thats why the loop is executed but it does nothing.
As mentioned in the comment a `while(konec == 0); { //do stuff }` is equal to a empty while loop `while(konec == 0) {}`